# PHP: GD reference to binary

Tags: php, gd, base64

I have a gd image reference (I've already manipulated the image how I want to), and now I want to store the image.  Instead of saving it directly to a file, is there a way I can get the binary data, that way I can convert it to base64 then save the base64 string.  The only option I've been able to find is imagejpeg($image), but that either saves it as a file or prints it directly to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can output to the buffer, and then capture it in this way.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```